# Pass in parameter to a react component when rendered from a method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am playing with React.js (I am new to it) and had a strange issue.

I can render a sub-component from the parent's render. This works:

```
<Station id="1" label="Start" />
```

I tried to extract this to a method:

```
renderStation(id, label) {
  return <Station id="{id}" label="{label}" />
}
// call it from the render() as
{this.renderStation(1, "Start")}
```

Strangely it passes in the strings "{id}" and "{label}" as props instead of "1" and "Start". Rendering a `<div>{id}</div>` from the same method just works fine. What is wrong?

See my playground with the repro here: https://jscomplete.com/repl?j=HybEKZuub

Comment: Just don't use quotes here `id="{id}"`.

Comment: check the [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx) how to specify the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the double quotes, and you are good to go.

`<Station id={id} label={label} />`

Comment: thx, works! for some reason i thought that curly braces just work like `${}` in template strings so they do a string-level replacement. But it seems that this is not true.

Answer (score 1):

To Avoid confusion..

```
let props = {
 "id":id,
 "label":label
}
<Station {...props} />
```

Comment: It's called spread attributes and it's aims for making passing of props easier... It is ES-6 feature.